# Huge lag running Python in PyCharm Windows in different Conda environments

Tags: python, pycharm, lag, conda, miniconda

I'm using PyCharm Professional and Miniconda3 to use TensorFlow in my project. Windows 10 v1703 build 15603.540.

It's all working just fine, except one issue: PyCharm lags for a tremendous amount of time (~22 sec) every time I launch any programs via interpreters in Conda environments.

Currently, I have 3 environments set up: root, tensorflow and tensorflow36.
Here some info:

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3:
#
asn1crypto                0.22.0                   py36_0
cffi                      1.10.0                   py36_0
conda                     4.3.25                   py36_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                    py36_1
cryptography              1.8.1                    py36_0
idna                      2.5                      py36_0
menuinst                  1.4.7                    py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2l                   vc14_0  [vc14]
packaging                 16.8                     py36_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1
pycosat                   0.6.2                    py36_0
pycparser                 2.17                     py36_0
pyopenssl                 17.0.0                   py36_0
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py36_0
python                    3.6.2                         0
pywin32                   220                      py36_2
requests                  2.14.2                   py36_0
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py36_1
setuptools                27.2.0                   py36_1
six                       1.10.0                   py36_0
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0

# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow:
#
bleach                    1.5.0                     <pip>
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0
decorator                 4.1.2                    py35_0
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_2  [vc14]
html5lib                  0.9999999                 <pip>
icu                       57.1                     vc14_0  [vc14]
jpeg                      9b                       vc14_0  [vc14]
libpng                    1.6.30                   vc14_1  [vc14]
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
Markdown                  2.6.9                     <pip>
matplotlib                2.0.2               np113py35_0
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0
networkx                  1.11                     py35_0
numpy                     1.13.1                    <pip>
numpy                     1.13.1                   py35_0
olefile                   0.44                     py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2l                   vc14_0  [vc14]
pandas                    0.20.3                   py35_0
pillow                    4.2.1                    py35_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1
protobuf                  3.4.0                     <pip>
pyparsing                 2.2.0                    py35_0
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_2
python                    3.5.4                         0
python-dateutil           2.6.1                    py35_0
pytz                      2017.2                   py35_0
pywavelets                0.5.2               np113py35_0
qt                        5.6.2                    vc14_6  [vc14]
scikit-image              0.13.0              np113py35_0
scipy                     0.19.1              np113py35_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py35_1
setuptools                36.4.0                    <pip>
sip                       4.18                     py35_0
six                       1.10.0                    <pip>
six                       1.10.0                   py35_1
tensorflow                1.3.0                     <pip>
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.1.5                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25420                    0
Werkzeug                  0.12.2                    <pip>
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
zlib                      1.2.11                   vc14_0  [vc14]

# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow36:
#
bleach                    1.5.0                     <pip>
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
certifi                   2016.2.28                py36_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0
decorator                 4.1.2                    py36_0
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_2  [vc14]
html5lib                  0.9999999                 <pip>
icu                       57.1                     vc14_0  [vc14]
jpeg                      9b                       vc14_0  [vc14]
libpng                    1.6.30                   vc14_1  [vc14]
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
Markdown                  2.6.9                     <pip>
matplotlib                2.0.2               np113py36_0
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0
networkx                  1.11                     py36_0
numpy                     1.13.1                   py36_0
numpy                     1.13.1                    <pip>
olefile                   0.44                     py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2l                   vc14_0  [vc14]
pillow                    4.2.1                    py36_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1
protobuf                  3.4.0                     <pip>
pyparsing                 2.2.0                    py36_0
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_2
python                    3.6.2                         0
python-dateutil           2.6.1                    py36_0
pytz                      2017.2                   py36_0
pywavelets                0.5.2               np113py36_0
qt                        5.6.2                    vc14_6  [vc14]
scikit-image              0.13.0              np113py36_0
scipy                     0.19.1              np113py36_0
setuptools                36.4.0                   py36_0
setuptools                36.4.0                    <pip>
sip                       4.18                     py36_0
six                       1.10.0                    <pip>
six                       1.10.0                   py36_0
tensorflow                1.3.0                     <pip>
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.1.5                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25420                    0
Werkzeug                  0.12.2                    <pip>
wheel                     0.29.0                    <pip>
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py36_0
zlib                      1.2.11                   vc14_0  [vc14]
```

Here's a [video demonstration](https://youtu.be/gvOfYz5xJAk).
Short text version:

I wrote a simple script

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Running using Conda's root Python 3.6.2 interpreter get's it done in appx 1 second.

Running using Conda's tensorflow36 environment Python 3.6.2 interpreter get's it done in appx 22 seconds.

Running using Conda's tensorflow environment Python 3.5.3 interpreter get's it done in appx 23 seconds.

Maybe it's due to plenty of packages installed, but... Script executes almost instantly using python.exe file in environment folder, either tensorflow (Python 3.5.4), or tensorflow36 (Python 3.6.2).

So it should be PyCharm problem, right? And it can be got rid off? I'm really enjoying PyCharm, and I want it to run smoothly.

Looking forward to hearing from you, StackOverflow community!